# Bash Scripting Wildcards in Conditions

Tags: linux, bash

I wish to check for proper user input as such (pseudo code)

```
userInput=""

#check until user enters 'y' OR 'Y' OR 'n' OR 'N'

while [[ "$userInput" != "[yYnN]" ]] ; do

     read userInput

done
```

My idea is to use the `[]` wild card for matching but what is the proper way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Yes. Don't use double quotes around the regexp. Do surround the expression with double brackets.

Comment: @AdamLiss ...well, this one has additional problems (using `[ ]` rather than `[[ ]]`, missing whitespace between the `while` and the test command following).

Comment: @theta `[` is a command, not syntax. Like other commands (and much other syntax), it needs to be separated from things that follow it with whitespace. `while [`, not `while[`. And glob matches need `[[ ]]`, not `[ ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
while true; do
case $userInput in
  y|Y|n|N)
    break
    ;;
  *)
    # read more input
    ;;
esac
done
```

If you're not concerned with portability, you can use

```
while [[ ! $userInput =~ [yYnN] ]]; do
```

Comment: If your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, the latter is definitely legal (re: "not concerned with portability").